# Bash: check if txt files exist in a dir and if yes, process them with aria2c

Tags: bash, file

OK, so, I'm trying to create a script that...

a. Will look in a folder where I drop my txt notes, and if any of them starts with "a2c_" it will recognize it as an "aria2c download list". Which brings as to...

b. Will pass the first of the matching files to aria2c, together with a directory name similar to the txt file, so that it will download each URL found in the txt to the same-named directory.

I've ended up with this..:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PARAMETERS: _______________________________
workingdir="/home/username/downloads/"
#___________________________________________

echo Working dir is: $workingdir
mkdir -p $workingdir
echo "Making dir"
cd $workingdir

if [ -f a2c_* ]
then
        echo "Found files"
        mkdir -p !a2c_downloaded
        echo "Making !a2c_downloaded dir"
        counter=0
        echo "Set counter to 0"
        for f in a2c_*.txt
        do
                counter=$((counter+1))
                echo Download List File is: $f
                echo $counter file processing.
                tempfile=${f%%.*}
                tempfile="`echo "$tempfile" | sed ' s/a2c_//' `"
                downdir=$tempfile
                echo Download Dir is: $downdir
                mkdir -p $downdir
                echo ___________________________________________
                echo $endfilename
                aria2c --auto-file-renaming -i $f -d $downdir --force-sequential
                echo "Will download $f to $downdir"
                sleep 5
                mv $f !a2c_downloaded/
        done
else
        echo "No files found"
fi
```

...that worked when I tested it. Today, one day later, I throw some a2c_*.txt files in the dir and I'm met with "unexpected operator" errors. Any ideas? And is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

_UPDATED: **_________________________________**

```
#!/bin/bash
#PARAMETERS: _______________________________
workingdir="/home/username/downloads/"
MatchPattern="a2c_*"
#___________________________________________

echo Working dir is: $workingdir
mkdir -p $workingdir
echo "Making dir"
cd $workingdir

#if [ -f a2c_* ];
#if [ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "a2c_*.txt" 2>/dev/null | grep "a2c_*" ]
#if [ -f a2c_* ]
#if [ "$?" = "0" ];
echo "Match Pattern set as $MatchPattern"
echo "Now looking in $workingdir for $MatchPattern"
echo "Manual list:"
echo "_________________________________________"
MatchList=$(ls -1 "$MatchPattern")
echo "$MatchList"
echo "_________________________________________"
if ls -1 $MatchPattern >/dev/null 2>&1
then
        echo "Found files"
        mkdir -p !a2c_downloaded
        echo "Making !a2c_downloaded dir"
        counter=0
        echo "Set counter to 0"
        for f in a2c_*.txt
        do
                counter=$((counter+1))
                echo "Download List File is: $f"
                echo $counter file processing.
                tempfile=${f%%.*}
                tempfile="`echo "$tempfile" | sed ' s/a2c_//' `"
                downdir=$tempfile
                echo "Download Dir is: $downdir"
                mkdir -p "$downdir"
                echo ___________________________________________
                echo "$endfilename"
                aria2c --auto-file-renaming -i "$f" -d "$downdir" --force-sequential
                echo "Will download $f to $downdir"
                sleep 5
                mv "$f" !a2c_downloaded/
        done
else
        echo "No files found"
fi
```

...The above works, after some fixes http://www.shellcheck.net/ told me to do. Problem is, it advises me to use double quotes in line:

```
if ls -1 $MatchPattern >/dev/null 2>&1
```

like

```
if ls -1 "$MatchPattern" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

..."Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.", but when I do, the script stops working for me. Should I leave it as it is? It seems to be working fine - for now.

Comment: Paste your code at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and read the red text.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it up to a point, by doing... ah, too much characters. I'll update my main post.

Comment: Note what the shellcheck message is: "Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting". In your case you *explicitly* want globbing. So quoting that is actively unhelpful for your case... but shellcheck can't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if [ -f a2c_* ]
then
```

You can try this:

```
file_exists() {
  for _i do
    [ -f "$_i" ] && break
  done
}
```

and then

```
if file_exists a2c_*
then
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't try your solution - yet - since after my last update (posted above, after "UPDATE") the code seems to work as it should. Is your solution better/more foolproof than...

    if ls -1 $MatchPattern >/dev/null 2>&1
    then

...I'm using now?

Comment: @ducklord. You can use both, but using `ls` means calling an external program, whereas this is a pure shell solution, so this is a little bit more efficient. Also `ls` checks for the existence of directory entry, not per se for the presence of a file, so it is equivalent to `[ -e file ]` rather than `[ -f file ]` so the shell option is more precise..

Comment: Ah, I see. So, off I go to swap the function I use with the one you propose :-)

Thanks!